# Get path from file descriptor when path is longer than PATH_MAX

Tags: c, linux, fanotify

I receive filesystem events from fanotify. Sometimes I want to get an absolute path to a file that's being accessed.

Usually, it's not a problem - `fanotify_event_metadata` contains a file descriptor `fd`, so I can call `readlink` on `/proc/self/fd/<fd>` and get my path.

However, if a path exceeds `PATH_MAX` `readlink` can no longer be used - it fails with `ENAMETOOLONG`. I'm wondering if there's a way to get a file path in this case.

Obviously, I can `fstat` the descriptor I get from a fanotify and traverse the entire filesystem looking for files with identical device ID and inode number. But this approach is not feasible for me performance-wise (even if I optimize it to ignore paths shorter than `PATH_MAX`).

I've tried getting a parent directory by reopening `fd` with `O_PATH` and calling `openat(fd, "..", ...)`. Obviously, that failed because `fd` doesn't refer to a directory. I've also tried examining contents of a buffer after a failed `readlink` call (hoping it contains partial path). That didn't work either.

So far I've managed to get long paths for files inside the working directory of a process that opened them (fanotify events contain a `pid` of a target process, so I can read `/proc/<pid>/cwd` and get the path to the root from there). But that is a partial solution.

Is there a way to get an absolute path from a file descriptor without traversing the whole filesystem? Preferably the one that will work with kernel 2.6.32/glibc 2.11.

*Update:* For the curious. I've figured out why calling `readlink("/proc/self/fd/<fd>",  ...` with a buffer large enough to store the entire path doesn't work.

Look at the implementation of [do_proc_readlink](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/base.c#L1599). Notice that it doesn't use provided `buffer` directly.  Instead, it allocates a single page and uses it as a temporary buffer when it calls [d_path](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/dcache.c#L3236). In other words, no matter how large is `buffer`, `d_path` will always be limited to a size of a page. Which is 4096 bytes on amd64. Same as `PATH_MAX`! The `-ENAMETOOLONG` itself is returned by [prepend](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/dcache.c#L2988) when it runs out of mentioned page.

Comment: Is the final resolved path without links and/or `.`/`..` elements longer than `PATH_MAX`?  If not, `realpath()` might work for you:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html

Comment: Aren't paths supposed to be, well, shorter than `PATH_MAX` characters? This sounds strange.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, `realpath` needs a path in the first place. All I have is a file descriptor and a PID.

Comment: @unwind No. I can't speak for all filesystems but on something like ext4 you can pretty much keep creating nested directories until you run out of inodes.

Comment: @NikitaKakuev *`realpath` needs a path in the first place.*  So does `readlink()`.  How are you getting *that* to work?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Exactly as I've stated in my answer - by calling `readlink` on `/proc/self/fd/<fd>`.

Comment: @NikitaKakuev So, you do have a path.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh, I forgot that `realpath` actually expands symlinks. In that case, I have a path (to a symlink), but it resolves to a path that's longer that PATH_MAX.

Comment: 1+ for bringing up this nice corner case issue. :-)

Comment: What happens if you pass a buffer longer than `PATH_MAX`?  For example: `char buffer[ 128 * 1024 ]; readlink( "/proc/self/fd/<fd>", buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );`  Because I don't see any checks for a path longer than `PATH_MAX` in the source code at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/base.c#L1599

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't see checks as well, but `readlink` still fails with `ENAMETOOLONG`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle On a second sight, I see the problem - `do_proc_readlink` doesn't use `buffer` directly. Instead, it allocates a page and uses it as a temporary buffer when it calls `d_path`. Consequently, `prepend` runs out of this buffer and returns `-ENAMETOOLONG`. A funny thing is that on amd64 PAGE_SIZE is 4096 bytes. Same as PATH_MAX.

Answer (score 1):

`readlink` *can* be used with a link target that's longer than `PATH_MAX`. There are two restrictions: the name of the link itself must be shorter than `PATH_MAX` (check, `"/proc/self/fd/<fd>"` is about 20 characters) and the provided output buffer must be large enough. You might want to call `lstat` first to figure out how big the output buffer should be, or just call `readlink` repeatedly with growing buffers.

Comment: That was the first thing I've tried (it's suggested by `man 2 readlink`) and it didn't work. I get `ENAMETOOLONG` for long paths despite the size of the buffer.

Comment: @NikitaKakuev: Just to double-check: you _did_ pass the actual buffer size as the third argument?

Answer (score 0):

the limitation of `PATH_MAX` births from the fact that the unix (or linux, from now) needs to bind the size of parameters passed to the kernel.  There's no limit on how deep a file hierarchy can grow, and always there's the possibility to access all files, independent on how deep they are in the filesystem hierarchy.  What is actually limited is the lenght of the string you can pass or receive from the kernel representing a file name.  This means you cannot create (because you have to pass the target path) a symlink longer than this length, but you can have easily paths far longer this limit.

When you pass a filename to the kernel, you can do that for two reasons, to name a file (or device, or socket, or fifo, or whatever), to open it, etc.  YOu do this and your filename goes first to a routine that converts that path into an inode (which is what the kernel manages actually).  That routine begins scanning from two possible point in the filesystem hierarchi.  Those points are the inode reference of the root inode and the inode reference of the curren working diretory of a process.  The selection of which inode to use as departure inode depends on the presence of a leading `/` character at the begining of the path.  From this point, up to `PATH_MAX` characters will be processed each time, but that can lead us deep enough that we cannot get to the root in one step only...

Suppose you use the path to change your current directory, and do a `chdir A/B/C/D/E/.../Z`.  Once there, you create new directories and do the same thing, `chdir AA/AB/AC/AD/AE/.../AZ`, then `chdir BA/BB/BC/BD/...` and so on... there's nothing in the system that forbids you to get so deep in the filesystem (you can try that yourself, I have done and tested before)  You can grow to a map that is by far larger than `PATH_MAX`.  But this only mean that you cannot get there directly from the filesystem root.  You can go there in steps, as much as the system allows you, and depending on where you fix you root directory (by means of the `chroot(2)` syscall) or your current directory (by means of the `chdir(2)` syscall)

probably you have notice (or not) that there's no system call to get your curren working directory path from root... There are several reasons for this:

- root inode and curren working inode are two local-to-process concepts.  Two processes in the same system can have different working directories, and also different root directories, up to the point that they are able to share nothing in common and no way from one's directory to reach the other.
- inode path can be ambiguous.  Well, this is not true for a directory, as it is not allowed two hard links to point to the same directory inode (this was possible in older unices, where directories had to be created with the `mknod(2)` system call, if you have access to some hp-ux v6 or old Unix SysV R4 you can create directories with a `...` entry ---pointing to the granparent of a directory or similar things, just being root and knowing how to use the `mknod(2)` syscall)  The idea is that when two links point to the same inode, which (or both) of then goes to the root, which one is the right path from the root inode to the current dir?
- curren inode and root can be separated by a path far enough to not fit in the `PATH_MAX` limit.
- there can be several different filesystems (and filesystem types) involved in getting to the root.  So this is not something that can be obtained only knowing the stored data in the disks, you must know the mounting table.

For these reasons, there's no direct support in the kernel to know the root path to a file.  And also there's no way to get the path (and this is what the `pwd(1)` command does) than to follow the `..` entry and get to the parent directory and search there a link that gets to the inode number of the current dir... and repeat this until the parent inode is the same as the last inode visited.  Only then you'll be in the root directory (your root directory, that is different in general of other processes root directories)

Just try this exercise:

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 10000 ]
do
    mkdir dir-$i
    cd dir-$i
    i=$(expr "$i" + 1)
done
```

and see how far you can go from the root directory in your hierarchy.

## NOTE 1

Another reason to be impossible to get the path to a file from an open descriptor is that you have access only to the inode (the path you used to `open(2)` it can have no relationship to the actual root path, as you can use symlinks and relative to the working directory, or changed root dir in between the open call and the time you want to access the path, it can even not exist, as you can have `unlink(2)`d it)  The inode information has no reference to the path to the inode, as there can be multiple (even millions) paths to a file. In the inode you have only a ref count, which means the number of paths that actually finish on that inode.

Comment: That's an... interesting perspective. But check out the update to my question. As it turns out, I wasn't running into "the limitation of `PATH_MAX`". The thing is that the implementation of `readlink` for `procfs` always works with a single-page buffer. If a path doesn't fit into this buffer, `-ENAMETOOLONG` is returned. If `do_proc_readlink` allocated a larger buffer, I would get the full path even if it was larger than PATH_MAX.

Comment: What do you mean with a single-page buffer.  Buffer to system call has not neccesary to be aligned to a page boundary, so it's easy for the buffer to span two consecutive pages (with only two bytes of path, and this is one char filename and the final '\0' character, you can get a path that uses two system pages)